# Apache Ant: Could not find the main class. Program will exit

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, eclipse-luna

I am trying to build a project using ANT using JDK 1.3 as a JRE (this version is required for this specific build). Also, I am using the following:

- Eclipse Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1).
- Ant version 1.7.1

When I try to build the project I get an error message saying: "Could not find the main class. Program will exit!". The JVM can't find the main class.

But when building using JDK 1.6.0 it works fine. What could be the cause of this error?

Why is it not possible to build with JDK 1.3?

I would really appreciate your input!

Best regards

Comment: Is there a Java class with a `main()` method somewhere in your source code?

Comment: How are you running Ant?  From the command line?

Comment: For me it seems like ant is not starting properly using jdk 1.3. Try to install older ant sersion, don't know which, and compile from command line.

Comment: Tim no i dont have a main()
Stephen I run it through eclipse
@ThrashBean, i tried with version 1.7.1 but still no luck

Comment: Can you post your build file? Older releases [http://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/binaries/]

Comment: Unfortunately i am not allowed to post anything from this project. But i would appreciate any other input from you guys!

Comment: If you are not allowed to post anything from the project, create a sample project from scratch that exhibits the same problem and share that (who knows, you might solve it by doing that).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your input guys. I have a workaround to this problem. I ran ANT through the command line. Then it everything works as intended. Thus, it seems that the eclipse version that i am using does not support the use of JDK1.3.